# How do I use assert (starting xsd)

Tags: xml, xsd, assert

I want to update homeAppliances.xsd so that the  element has a content (type) that depends on (is conditional to) the value of the kind attribute.

I also want to add more appliances with a different kind of home appliances

Notice that each  element has a kind attribute, which specifies whether the appliance is a stereo appliance or a juicer appliance.

My goal is that the output should only show those appliances that have a "kind" attribute

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<homeAppliances>

  <appliance kind="stereo">
      <description>My stereo</description>
      <brand>Sony</brand>
      <type>Hi-fi</type>
  </appliance>

  <appliance kind="juicer">
      <description>Theres just no substitute for a properly squeezed orange in the morning. 
         So delicate and refreshing. The finest hotels use mechanical juicers of this type for their 
         most discriminating guests. This is the largest selling juicer of its kind. Its a beautiful 
         little all-metal piece in baked enamel and polished chrome; it even won the Frankfurt Fair Award 
         for its design. Uses no electricity and produces no non-recyclable waste as do frozen juices.</description>
      <warranty>lifetime warranty</warranty>
      <name>OJ Home Juicer</name>
      <image>images\mighty_oj.gif</image>
      <cost>41.95</cost>
      <retailer>http://www.thewhitewhale.com/oj.htm</retailer>
  </appliance>
```

and this is my xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>



<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified">


<xs:complexType name="appliance">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="warranty" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="kind" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="stereoAppliance">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="appliance">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="brand" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="juiceAppliance">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="appliance">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="image" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="weight" type="xs:unsignedByte" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="cost" type="xs:decimal" />
                <xs:element name="retailer" type="xs:anyURI" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:element name="homeAppliances">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="appliance" type="appliance" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible. XSD doesn't support conditional constraints. What I suggest is to get rid of the type attribute and use its value as a name of elements.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<homeAppliances>
    
    <stereo>
        <description>My stereo</description>
        <brand>Sony</brand>
        <type>Hi-fi</type>
    </stereo>
    
    <juicer>
        <description>Theres just no substitute for a properly squeezed orange in the morning. 
            So delicate and refreshing. The finest hotels use mechanical juicers of this type for their 
            most discriminating guests. This is the largest selling juicer of its kind. Its a beautiful 
            little all-metal piece in baked enamel and polished chrome; it even won the Frankfurt Fair Award 
            for its design. Uses no electricity and produces no non-recyclable waste as do frozen juices.</description>
        <warranty>lifetime warranty</warranty>
        <name>OJ Home Juicer</name>
        <image>images\mighty_oj.gif</image>
        <cost>41.95</cost>
        <retailer>http://www.thewhitewhale.com/oj.htm</retailer>
    </juicer>
</homeAppliances>
```

In the XSD you can describe it via `xs:choice`:

```xml
<xs:element name="homeAppliances">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="stereo" type="stereoAppliance"/>
                    <xs:element name="juice" type="juiceAppliance"/>
                </xs:choice>                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
```